# angular --prod build and radio button

Tags: angular

I have styled radio buttons in my app like below.  running the app with ng serve or building with the --dev flag works fine.  If I run it in --prod mode however then the click event will not fire.  setting an id on input element and for attribute on label should fire that event.  Just curious if anybody has found a way to make this work.

```
  <input type="radio" value="chart" name="displayType" [ngModel]="displayType" id="chart-radio" (click)="changeDisplay('chart')"/>
  <label for="chart-radio" >Chart</label>
```

I should also point out that the radio checked attribute does appear to change when clicking on it.  it is just that the click event does not fire

Comment: Is `changeDisplay` public? Do you see any error in the console? Another question: you talk about the label... do you test by clicking on the radio button?

Comment: changeDisplay is public and no error.  the function just isnt called.  If I put the click event on the label then it works but it should work with the client event on the input.  in fact it does in dev build

Comment: You can try putting the input element inside of the label content. The click event handler may have to be set on the label in that case (e.g. `<label (click)="changeDisplay('chart')"><input ... />Chart</label>`).

Comment: for now I just switched (click) to (change) and then got rid of ngModel and just used [value] and [checked]